# continuity and differentiability of two variables.

Tags: analysis

Consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$$f(x,y) =  (3x-2y+y^2 , 4x+5y+y^2)$$
then which of the following is true?

1. $f$ is discontinuous at (0,0)
2. $f$ is continuous at (0,0) and all directional derivatives exists at (0,0)
3. $f$ is differentiable at (0,0) but the derivative $Df(0,0)$ is not invertible
4. $f$ is differentiable at (0,0) and the derivative $Df(0,0)$ is invertible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All coordinates are polynomial functions in $x,y$ .So f is continuous.

$D_vf(0)=f(tv)-f(0)=((3tv_1-2tv_2+t^2v_2^2),(4tv_1+5tv_2+t^2v_2^2))$

So $\displaystyle \frac{f(tv)-f(0)}{t}=\frac{((3tv_1-2tv_2+t^2v_2^2),(4tv_1+5tv_2+t^2v_2^2))}{t}=((3v_1-2v_2+tv_2^2),(4v_1+5v_2+tv_2^2))$

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(tv)-f(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}((3v_1-2v_2+tv_2^2),(4v_1+5v_2+tv_2^2))=(3v_1-2v_2,4v_1+5v_2)$

So the directional derivative exists.

Now the derivative will be

$\begin{pmatrix}
3&-2\\
4&5
\end {pmatrix}$ (First column is made up of $D_{(1,0)}f(0)$ and the 2nd column is made up of $D_{(0,1)}f(0)$)which is invertible.